# Fragment-like activity backstack behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

I have following scenario and want to avoid using Fragments.

`Act X <-> (Act A <-> Act B <-> Act C) --> Act X.`

There shall be a back navigation possible. After finishing the process (A-B-C) i want to go back to my entry point (from backstack e.g. Act X). Also i want to be able to close the process at any point. E.g.: User is at Act B and presses `Cancel`-Button --> go back to entry Point (Act X).

I want to have a separate "Activity back-stack" where i can cancel a specific process at any point (A, B or C) and go back to my entry point (X, ...). Is this possible using only Activities? I tried using a separate `taskAffinity` (in the Manifest) with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but i want to avoid starting a "separate application".

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, or perhaps the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. It is very unclear from your description what you expect the state of the back stack to be after the user progresses through the chain of activities that you have depicted.

Comment: I want to have a "normal" back-press behaviour. 
So the A-B-C Activities are for a Configuration inside my app. And when i finish the process i want to go back to my entry point. Also i want to provide standard back-navigation **plus** a chance to cancel the whole "config" process at any time/activity.

So A-B-C act like a kind of group

Comment: "I want to have a "normal" back-press behaviour" -- that did not clarify things. When the user reaches the right-hand "Act Home", and then presses BACK, what appears? Act C? Another instance of Act Home? The user's home screen, because the right-most Act Home is the only thing on the back stack? Something else?

Comment: No - when user finishes process in Act C then he comes back to Act Home from the backstack and when hitting back again then open activity from backstack before Home was started (if there was none then close application)

Comment: Try the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Comment: ok but how to `finish()` the "Activity-Group"? i want to be able to go back each step and also be able to finish all

Comment: As I have written twice previously, try the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. Quoting the docs for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`: "f set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent. ". So, use that flag (or perhaps both) when starting the right-hand Act Now.

Comment: as i wrote before --> i dont want to start a new Act Home --> i want to get it back from the backstack and not recreate it.
Act A, B, C can all go back with backpressed from C --> B --> A AND all shall be able to close the the whole process by clicking on a "cancel" button and go back to Home without starting the activity with an intent but get it from backstack

Comment: "i want to get it back from the backstack and not recreate it" -- and that is what `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` does. Please re-read my last comment, particularly the quote from the documentation. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` also does this, but it does not clear the other activities from the stack, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is there is not such things like "popBackstack" until a point with Activities. I think you can:

- Start a new Intent with Act X and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to bring the Act X to front if exists, when the user presses cancel
- Override `onBackPressed` in Act A, B, C to do the same as the option above when the user presses `back`. But in that case you'll maybe have to specify the animation to simulate the `back` effect.

I don't know why you need to use only activities but it'd be easier if you had 2 activities (X and Y). And Y contains fragments A, B, C. Like that you could override `onBackPressed` in Act Y and finish the activity when the user press `back` on any of the fragments. You'd automatically go back to Act X.